# column formula help

Tags: infopath, excel, calculated-column-formula

I've asked a question a couple days ago, wich gave me the answer

```
=IF( OR(INT(A)+INT(B)+INT(C) = 3, INT(A)+INT(B)+INT(C) = 0),  "Accepted", "Not Accepted" )
```

But that only works if they have to fill in every question, but they can leave some blank if they are not applyable.

So basicly what i want is

```
 if 
A=1
B=1
C=1

It should return "Accepted", 

When it is
A=1
B=2
C=1

it should give "Notaccepted"

If 
A=2
B=2
C=1

it should still say "Not accepted"   

but If they leave one blank( value of a blank answer is 0) 
A=2
B=0
C=1

it should still say "Accepted"
```

While this formula still says not accepted ( or accepted, with one hell of a lot counting coinsidence)
(I've made this form in InfoPath)
I want people not having to fill in everything. So they can leave some questions blank(value 0) because not every question is applyable on the same situation.

Can anyone help me out of this struggle?

Comment: I didn't understand.. in your last example if they leave blank for one question, but for A=2 it should finally give Not Accepted right? Did you mean if any of the questions is left blank, the final is always Accepted?

Comment: @arsalan-adam-khatri No, Like if you leave one blank, it should'nt change the outcome. So if someone answers with these answers:

    A=1
    B=2
    C=0 (left blank)

Its "Unacceptable"Because of B's value 2.

But if they do 

A=0 (because blank = 0)
B=1
C=1
 
it should be accepted. Because both, B&C, are answered as "Acceptable"(value 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than I guess you should simply use:

`=IF(OR(INT(A)=2,INT(B)=2,INT(C)=2), "Not Accepted", "Accepted")`

Comment: If i use that and i press "Not acceptable"(value 2) it gives accepted aswell :/

Comment: @RickStandaert please try updated answer

Comment: @ArslanAdamKhatri Thank you so much! :p You've answered some questions of me before if I'm not mistaken. Thanks for everything ^^

Comment: No problem, yes your last question was also answered by me.. Glad it helped.